# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ProcessBuilder$Redirect

Tags: java

I am getting this error when I launch my job. It works on my local machine but it fails if I upload war file to tomcat7 on server. The application is started but it fails at run time.

This is the code,

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    File log = new File(this.logFilePath);

    if (!log.exists()) {
        log.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }

    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
    Process p = pb.start();
```

and the stack trace

```
ERROR: org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step eu.createBatchStep in job eu
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ProcessBuilder$Redirect
    at com.stockopedia.symfony.Symfony.run(Symfony.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy29.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.stockopedia.batch.foundation.tasklets.SystemCommandTasklet.execute(SystemCommandTasklet.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy22.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:402)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:326)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:162)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:141)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Initially I though it could be because file does not exist, but I tried creating file manually, but still getting same error.

Comment: Which java-version do you use? `ProcessBuilder.Redirect` is available from java 7

Comment: java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.11.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: hmm redirectOutput is not supported in java 6 ?

Comment: So looks like you have to upgrade your java version to java 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors tells that it can't find class *Redirect* in class path.

This class is available from **Java 1.7** [you can check it there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html), so you can't use it in earlier versions on Java.

I suppose you use Java 1.7 or higher in your development environment, but tomcat is run under Java 1.6 where class Redirect and method redirectOutput(Redirect) does not exist.

So try to upgrade your java on server or use API specific to Java 1.6.